# Intelligent credit cards fields iOS

Tags: ios, swift, credit-card

i'm currently developing an app for iOS 8 in swift with a credit card payment functionality.

I searched on the web for a library with intelligent credit card fields, but all i could find is BKMoneyKit, which is not really customizable, and doesn't fit my needs.

What i want is something with fancy features, like telling you if your card is a visa/mastercard when you enter the number, adding the "/" between month and year of expiration date etc... I've already used card.io, but it doesn't offer the possibility to include it's intelligent fields in my view, like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255345/can-i-use-card-io-credit-card-number-text-field-in-ios-in-a-custom-enter-manuall) by the developer himself.

Does anybody knows a tool like this ?

Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionalities you are asking for are provided by the [PaymentKit](https://github.com/stripe/PaymentKit) library.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thanks !